# How to create a checkboxInput which, when checked, expands a box with options?

Tags: r, shiny

For the code below I need to add a snippet that would allow me, after selecting an option in the first checkboxInput (choice), to expand a separate box with the rest of the options. How can I make these options closable.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "X"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        checkboxInput("choice", "Are you into it?"),
        checkboxGroupInput("stages", "Stages: ", choices = c("First", "Second", "Third")),
        selectInput("status", "Status of this card: ", choices = c(" ", "Active", "Closed")),
        dateInput(inputId = "date", label = "Choose date : "),
        sliderInput(inputId = "inactivity", label = "Time of inactivity ", min = 6, max = 24, value = 10)
        ),
    dashboardBody(
        dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `conditionalPanel` to display other inputs when the user clicks the first `checkboxInput`:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "X"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        checkboxInput("choice", "Are you into it?"),
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.choice',
        checkboxGroupInput("stages", "Stages: ", choices = c("First", "Second", "Third")),
        selectInput("status", "Status of this card: ", choices = c(" ", "Active", "Closed")),
        dateInput(inputId = "date", label = "Choose date : "),
        sliderInput(inputId = "inactivity", label = "Time of inactivity ", min = 6, max = 24, value = 10)
    )),
    dashboardBody(
        dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this :

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "X"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        checkboxInput("choice", "Are you into it?"),
        uiOutput("group"),
        selectInput("status", "Status of this card: ", choices = c(" ", "Active", "Closed")),
        dateInput(inputId = "date", label = "Choose date : "),
        sliderInput(inputId = "inactivity", label = "Time of inactivity ", min = 6, max = 24, value = 10)
        ),
    dashboardBody(
        dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
    )
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  output$group <- renderUi {
    if (input$choices==TRUE) {
      checkboxGroupInput("stages", "Stages: ", choices = c("First", "Second", "Third"))
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works and if it's the result you're looking for !

Comment: Ok, sorry but I don't really understand what you want to do here